# Openlayers cluster stragegy total count

Tags: vector, wfs, layers, features, openlayers-2

How can I get total feature count  of vector layer:

```
var mylayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(null, {
        "protocol": myWFSProtocol,
        "styleMap": style,
        "strategies": [
            new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),
            new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()
        ]
        "filter": new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
            filters: [
                new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    "type": OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.NOT_EQUAL_TO,
                    "property": attributeNames.catid,
                    "value": "null"
                })
            ]
        })
    });
```

when I get mylayer.features.length it returns 5 but it actually 12. Is there any property of vector layer that gives total count.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the number of features in the cluster strategy object. If there were no more strategies added to the layer, the correct path to the array is the following:

```
mylayer.strategies[1].features
```